# How to match with two regex Expression?

Tags: java, regex

I should check if that string is valid. So i can i check UUID parts with this regex expression

```
private String UUID = "([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})"

private String url = "customers/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000111/areas/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000222/orders/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000555/invoices/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000777/employees/2018-10-31T00:27:31.205+0000.jpg"
```

like this

```
Pattern JPG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            String.format("customers/%s/areas/%<s/orders/%<s/invoices/%<s/employees/", UUID));

Matcher m = JPG_PATTERN.matcher(url);

if (m.find()) {
System.out.println("found);
}
```

But when i add another regex to check last part of the string. It doesn't work.

```
private String EXTENSION = "(?:mov|jpg)";

 Pattern JPG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
                String.format("customers/%s/areas/%<s/orders/%<s/invoices/%<s/employees/%s", UUID, EXTENSION));

    Matcher m = JPG_PATTERN.matcher(url);

    if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found);
    }
```

How can use these two apart regex expression and check if the string is valid?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. The value after `/employees/` is `2018-10-31T00:27:31.205+0000.jpg`, but your regex only matches `mov|jpg`, e.g. it would match `/employees/jpg`, but it can't match the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match filename: `2018-10-31T00:27:31.205+0000`.
Change extension regex to `String EXTENSION = ".+(?:mov|jpg)";`

And change `find` to `matches`, otherwise .jpg1 is considered valid. Here is full the code:

```
private static String UUID = "([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})";

private static String url = "customers/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000111/areas/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000222/orders/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000555/invoices/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000777/employees/2018-10-31T00:27:31.205+0000.jpg";

private static String EXTENSION = ".+(?:mov|jpg)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern JPG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(String.format("customers/%s/areas/%<s/orders/%<s/invoices/%<s/employees/%s", UUID, EXTENSION));

    Matcher m = JPG_PATTERN.matcher(url);

    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version of your code.  The blocker I saw on your end seemed to be a misunderstanding of how `String#format` works.  Because you are trying to bind more than one placeholder, I suggest just using `%s` everywhere and then specifying each string explicitly.  Note that the pattern you want to use for the final path component for the extension is slightly different than what you suggested.

```
String UUID = "([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})";
String EXTENSION = ".*(?:mov|jpg)$";
String pattern = String.format("^customers/%s/areas/%s/orders/%s/invoices/%s/employees/%s", UUID, UUID, UUID, UUID, EXTENSION);
System.out.println(pattern);

^customers/([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/areas/
    ([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/orders/
    ([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/invoices/
    ([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/employees/.*(?:mov|jpg)$
```

Follow the link below for a running regex demo which shows that the above pattern matched your test URL.

### Demo